# No Matching Host for bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: capistrano3

I'm using capistrano 3.0.1 and capistrano-rails 1.1.0 for deployment. The deployment works so far well, only the `assets:precompile` doesn't get executed. That phases is every time skipped with this message:

```
WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403'" 1>&2; false; fi
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for bundle exec rake assets:precompile
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403'" 1>&2; false; fi
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403/public/assets/manifest* /var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403/assets_manifest_backup
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/versioneye/releases/20140111161403'" 1>&2; false; fi
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env find public/images public/javascripts public/stylesheets -exec touch -t 201401111614.03 {} ';'; true
```

I defined only 1 role in `config/deploy/stagging`.

```
role :app, %w{cap@aws-7}
```

And in `config/deploy.rb` I set the asset_roles like this:

```
set :assets_roles, [:app]   # Defaults to [:web]
```

Any idea why `assets:precompile` dosn't get executed?

Answer (score 7):

No Matching Host could mean you don't have a host set up for that role. I had taken a shortcut too, and only filled in `role :app`, then had this problem, and filled in `role :web`, still had problem, and filled in `role :db`, and I can successfully deploy, including the whenever writing to crontab.

```
role :app %w{cap@aws-7}
role :web %w{cap@aws-7}
role :db  %w{cap@aws-7}
```

Where cap@aws-7 is your deployuser@hostname.com

Answer (score 1):

Somehow assets_roles doesn't have any effect in my case. After I set explicitly the web role in `config/deploy/stagging` it worked.

```
role :web, %w{cap@aws-7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to capistrano-rails **1.1.1**

capistrano-rails **1.1.0** hasn't the 'set :assets_roles..' feature.